# Role-Specific Repository vs Specific Repository

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I wasn't aware of Role-Specific Repositories, until I found this [article](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/03/ddd-repository-implementation-patterns/):

> Instead of a catch-all repository that exposes every method under the
>   sun, we could alternatively apply the Interface Segregation Principle
>   for role-based interfaces, and define interfaces that expose only what
>   one class needs.
>
> ```
> public interface IProductRepositoryForNewOrder
> {
>     Product[] FindDiscontinuedProducts();
> }
> ```
>
> A single repository implementation implements all Product repository
>   interfaces, but only the single method needed is exposed and used by
>   the caller.

a) Is the difference between the two in that with *Specific Repositories* we have one specific contract per Aggregate Root, while *Role-Specific Repositories* we can have several contracts per Aggregate Root, each of these contracts tailored to the needs of particular caller operating on Aggregate Root?

b) In your opinion, what are the pros and cons of each of the two patterns?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

Yesterday I found one of your [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734000/is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-for-domain-code-to-request-data-it-needs) where in essence you argue that Role-Specific repository pattern should be used:

> "Another option is to use a lambda instead of OrdersSelectorService.
>   If lambdas aren't available in your language then it should be an
>   interface. The benefit over passing OrderRepository is based on the
>   interface segregation principle the goal of which is to reduce
>   needless coupling. It is unlikely that a behavior on Customer needs
>   all the methods on OrderRepository, instead it needs a specific
>   function, so make that explicit."

Why in above excerpt you advocate the use of Role-Specific repository pattern, but here you appear to recommend using it only in special circumstances. Is the example in the other topic a special circumstance (aside – in no way am I saying you're contradicting yourself, I just don't see how the two examples are different with regards to the using or not using Role-Specific pattern)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Yes. This is the interface segregation principle at play; making roles/use cases explicit. The benefit is that of reducing  and "cleaning" dependencies.

b) For me, the primary con of role-specific approach is the proliferation of interfaces and the resulting increases in wiring, references, etc. This con however can be regarded as such not due to a flaw in the principle, but more-so in the programming language. In a functional language, such as F# for instance, interface segregation is the default approach due to the proliferation of functions instead of interfaces. In a sense, functions are a "sharper" tool.

The pro of the non-role-specific approach is that it can be seen as a single language element, an interface or class, that defines the data access contract. In certain cases, it is valuable to evaluate an architecture from a technical angle.

Comment: 1 - "In certain cases, it is valuable to evaluate an architecture from a technical angle" Meaning if I'm using C#, then go with non-role-specific approach, and if I'm using say F#, then go with role-specific approach? 2 - I assume you prefer non-role-specific approach when using C#?

Comment: By that I meant that it can be valuable to look at the entire data access contract associated with an aggregate - the entire repository interface. I use the role-specific approach in C# as well, it just has some downsides.

Comment: In that case, the focus is on the entity, not the repository. The repository could be implemented in a role-specific or not. So yes, I am advocating interface segregation, but at the entity level, not the repository level. Whether ISP applies for repositories is the subject of this question and as you can see there are positives and negatives.

Comment: But why would it matter whether it's the entity that needs to be serviced by repository or whether some Application service needs to be serviced by Repository? Thus why wouldn't applying Role-Specific Interface pattern at entity level (ie when entity needs to be serviced by repo) cause same problems as when applied at Repository level (ie when Application service needs to be serviced by repo)?

Comment: As I see it, the difference is quite subtle and this may ultimately be a matter of preference as neither approach is absolutely wrong. The reason I'd use ISP in the entity case by providing explicit dependencies expressed as lambdas, is because lambdas don't need a separate declaration and as a result, they don't "pollute" the domain layer. Also, being explicit at the entity level is, IMO, more important than being explicit at the repository level, which is a more technical concern.

Comment: My apologies for dragging this, I will make this my final reply 1 - "The reason I'd use ISP in the entity case by providing explicit dependencies expressed as lambdas" And if instead of lambdas we'd use IOrderSelector implemented by OrderRepository 2 - "which is a more technical concern" What do you mean?

Comment: Using IOrderSelector is also find, but perhaps unnecessary because a lambda will express the same contract without having to declare an additional interface. What I mean by "a more technical concern" is that from the perspective of your domain, persistence is a technical concern.  Part of the idea with DDD is to facilitate [functional cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) which basically amounts to expressing your domain clearly in the code, hence POCOs, persistence ignorance, etc. A repository, being part of persistence, is less "interesting" than the domain..

Answer (score 2):

I'm all for SOLID code, but the Interface Segregation Principle does have its limits, especially in a DDD context.

*[ nitpicker mode ]*

If you apply ISP to the letter, you can pretty much take the statement about repositories from the article and change it a little to say that

> Classes that use a **domain entity** rarely use every method inside of it.

Therefore, for each domain entity, you should create as many interfaces as there are clients of the entity, with only the methods relevant to the client in each interface, and make the entity implement these interfaces.

Of course, this is absurd and nobody will ever do that. But hey, ISP is supposed to be a universal OO concept, isn't it ?

*[/ nitpicker mode ]*

Now if we look back at the original reason why ISP is, it's supposed to fight fat interfaces, i.e. ones that are not cohesive. But isn't a repository cohesive in itself ? Isn't it a basic, atomic DDD building block ? Does it deserve to be split in dozens of mini query objects ? Besides, isn't each class in our domain supposed to be aligned with the Ubiquitous Language ? That's hardly the case with interfaces such as `ProductRepoInterfaceForClient1`, `ProductRepoInterfaceForClient2`, `ProductRepoInterfaceForClient3`...

Don't get me wrong, ISP is still useful, especially as a way to detect when an interface's contract is way more heterogeneous than it should be. Uncle Bob's [original paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/downing/papers/InterfaceSegregation1996.pdf) on ISP has good examples of that - see the "Interface Pollution" paragraph and the ATM example.

But once a reasonable level of cohesion has been attained, ISP should IMO not be applied blindly, especially if it conflicts with basic DDD principles, or floods your code base with hundreds of interfaces that become a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: Are you also against using Specific Repository pattern?

Comment: +1 for conflicts with basic DDD principles and maintenance nightmare.  The idea of bounded context removes the need for ISP.

Comment: @user437291 No I'm not, I generally define my repositories something along the lines of `public class ProductRepository : NHibernateRepository<Product>, IProductRepository` where `IProductRepository` is defined in the Domain layer and `NHibernateRepository<T>` in the Infrastructure layer.

Comment: I assume NHibernateRepository<T> implements generic repository IRepository<T>?

Comment: Yes, you could do that if you want other persistence mechanisms besides NHibernate. But if you only need NHibernate and mock repositories (for testing), you can pretty much live without it, since `IProductRepository` already makes a perfect interface for your mocks.

Comment: Your point about explicit roles on repositories vs domain objects is interesting. Udi Dahan actually [proposes making domain object roles explicit as well](http://www.slideshare.net/deimos/udi-dahan-intentions-and-interfaces). Personally, I tend to avoid making domain object roles explicit but I do make repository roles explicit. Tradeoffs either way.

Comment: @eulerfx Nice. Thanks for the link, I had no idea someone had taken the concept to such an extreme. I'll watch his talk on InfoQ too. I still can't help but think it creates more maintainability problems than it solves, and moves the cursor down to an excessively small interface size. Microscopic isn't cohesive.

Comment: @guillaume31: I agree, too much friction, but important concept.